# get back ubuntu software center, software & updates

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I installed a fresh copy of elementary OS 0.4. I could find `ubuntu software center` and `software & updates`. I guess these were depreciated and replaced with the elementary version called `AppCenter`. But how do I get them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Terminal`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk   # for Software & Updates
sudo apt install software-center           # for Ubuntu Software Center
```